# Eclipse "Class File Editor" Source Not Found While Debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have a project in Java that I am stepping through and when I'm using external libraries e.g. `jdom.jar` I end up hammering step over to get out on the "Class File Editor". I really don't care about whats in these libraries I'm just using them to process things for my own code.

Is there anyway to get around this popping up?

It's so frustrating hammering step over every time I accidentally step into a class file which I know has no source and is completely pointless me looking through.

image below:

[image]

Comment: Press 'F7' for STEP Return and then be more careful next time... you shouldn't be decompiling libraries (especially not commercial ones).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are various solutions:

1. You can download the sources and attach them (select the dependency in the Package Explorer, open the Properties dialog for it, set the path under "Java Source Attachment")
2. If you don't have the source, install [JADClipse](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-decompile-java-classes-in-eclipse.html?page=2)
3. Use "Step Over" (<kbd>F6</kbd>) instead of "Step Into" (<kbd>F5</kbd>)
4. If you accidentally stepped into some code, use "Step Return" (<kbd>F7</kbd>) to run the whole method and resume debugging after it has returned.
5. You can tell Eclipse what you don't want to step into using "[step filters](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-usestepfilters.htm)".

Answer (score 9):

Simple way-- Works for me :)

Select Attach Source->(External Location Radio Box)External File->
Select src.zip from java/jdk1.x.x.xx folder

and done!!

Comment: If scr.zip link is broken, you need to: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-source` and then it sould work. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Go to **Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries**

Expand JRE System Library.

Expand rt.jar.

Select Source attachment and double click or Edit.
Type path the source code file (External File…) and press OK.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying that, but it reads "Source attachment: (None) - **non modifiable**" and I can't edit it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try
[JADClipse](http://greatwebguy.com/programming/eclipse/decompile-java-classes-automatically-in-eclipse-with-jadclipse-and-jad/)

At least you will see the code, and be able to step return and step resume more easily.
I don't think there is any way to skip the classes u dont have the source for.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Enhanced Class Decompiler from Eclipse Marketplace, restart when prompt.
2. Go to Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations, selected both "*.class" and "*.class without source" associating them to Class Decompiler Viewer as default.
3. In Preferences->Java->Decompiler check that the Default Class Decompiler suits your JDK version.

Answer (score 0):

open 
1- help 
2- Install New Software
in work with click at Add
http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update
add source code
then
in attach source chose 
external location
in patch click external file 
documents - eclipse - plugins -
choose package we just download (source code package)
example : com.android.ide.eclipse.source......
- 14 
sources.zip
i hope this work with you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle, port your dependencies to eclipse classpath by using the eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the option Java -> Debug -> "Use advanced source lookup (JRE 1.5 and higher)" checkbox resolves this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was in pom.xml of the debugged project.

In my dependent project - the dependency version was 1.9.3

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aaa</groupId>
            <artifactId>abcautomationlayer</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Whereas it should have been 1.9.3-SNAPSHOT. As the primary project has the version info in that way

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.aaa</groupId>
    <artifactId>abcautomationlayer</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

So changing from 1.9.3 -> 1.9.3-SNAPSHOT in dependent project did the trick