# Eclipse: Source not found error !!! Not able to resolve after trying multiple tricks

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I am trying to understand the spring-social-showcase example in Eclipse and wants to browse the source code for its dependent projects. When I try to jump to some declaration found in the spring social core package, I get the below error:

Class file editor

Source Not found: The jar file .....spring-social-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar has no source attachment. You can attach the source...

[image]

I tried these by reading the SO posts which didn't work for me:

1. Attach Source -> External Location -> External file and pointed to
   "spring-social-1.1.0.RELEASE.zip" in my system.
2. Attach Source ->
   External Location -> External folder and pointed to
   "spring-social-1.1.0.RELEASE" folder in my system.
3. Attach Source ->
   External Location -> External folder and pointed to
   "spring-social-1.1.0.RELEASE\spring-social-core\src\main\java\org\springframework\social\connect"
   folder where the specific java file lies.
4. In Project properties ->
   Java build path -> Libraries, specified the source attachment by
   pointing to the "spring-social-1.1.0.RELEASE.zip".
5. In Project
   properties -> Java build path -> Source, added folder as linked
   folder.
6. In Project properties -> Java build path -> Projects, added
   project as a dependent project.

All of these have failed for me and still I am seeing this error. Is there a problem with my Eclipse installation? How should I confirm this?

I am on verge of madness now, please save me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9940158/1079354

Comment: As I have mentioned, I have seen all these posts but the suggestions over there didn't help me.